# How to display the index and index+1 of a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I am writing a program which loops through every object in a string[] array to find an object which contains a given string.

I then need to display that object and the following object, however, I can only seem to get the object that contains the given string and cannot get the object directly following as well.

```
static void Search_Level_2()
{
    bool check = false;
    WriteLine("Search Level 2:\nChecking if sequence {0} is in file...", inputArray[3]);
    foreach (string line in sequences)
    {
        if (line.Contains(inputArray[3]))
        {
            WriteLine("Sequence Found!");
            WriteLine(line.ToString());
            check = true;
        }
    }
    if (!check)
    {
        WriteLine("Error: Sequence {0} not found", inputArray[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For this case you should use a for loop, as there is no way, in C#, to get the iteration of a foreach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with a `foreach` because behind the scenes `foreach` gets an enumerator on the collection you're accessing and every time the loop comes round, it calls MoveNext() on the enumerator. There isn't any access to that enumerator for you if foreach set it up but you're not prohibited from getting an enumerator yourself and calling next yourself to get the next item.. Buuuut there's no way to move the enumerator backwards so you start having to build hacks in to remember what was this time's next so that in the next iteration you can recall it as the current.. messy

Use a classic for instead:

```
for(int x = 0; x < sequences.Length-1; x++)
{
  var curr = sequences[x];
  var next = sequences[x+1];
}
```

Note the loop runs to (less than Length-1) so the attempt to access x+1 doesn't cause a crash on the last item

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines:

```
static void Search_Level_2()
{
    bool check = false;
    WriteLine("Search Level 2:\nChecking if sequence {0} is in file...", inputArray[3]);
    foreach (string line in sequences)
    {
        if (check)
        {
            WriteLine("Next line:");
            WriteLine(line);
            break;
        }

        if (line.Contains(inputArray[3]))
        {
            WriteLine("Sequence Found!");
            WriteLine(line);
            check = true;
        }

    }
    if (!check)
    {
        WriteLine("Error: Sequence {0} not found", inputArray[3]);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to only report the first occurrence and the line following the match.